# Get All Custom Taxonomy Images of Terms

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom taxonomy with 500+ terms is "dtcast"

I using this plugin for custom taxonomy images terms : [Advanced Category and Custom Taxonomy Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-category-and-custom-taxonomy-image/)

Now, I use this script to get list of all terms

```
<?php 
$tax = 'dtcast'; // your taxonomy name

// get the terms of taxonomy
$terms = get_terms( $tax, [
    'hide_empty' => false, // do not hide empty terms
]);

// loop through all terms
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    // display link to the term archive
    echo '<strong class="danny-vien"><a href="'. get_term_link( $term ) .'">'. $term->name .'</a></strong>';
}
?>
```

It’s work ok !

But i want to get images of terms.
Please help me to get it.

Comment: Hi. Can help me to show 10 item per page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
$image = get_taxonomy_image( $term->term_id );
```

Comment: Hi. Can help me to show 10 item per page?

Comment: Great! Glad it works. :) As for the 10 items per page, how are you displaying items?

Comment: I want to display 10 items per page as this images : https://i.ibb.co/PMCRcT1/2021-10-12-16-37-08.png

Comment: WP Themes using this code to get it : doo_pagination();

Comment: And this is full scipt for querry and page.

echo '<div id="archive-content" class="animation-2 items '.$maxwidth.'">';
if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
  get_template_part('inc/parts/item');
 }
}
echo '</div>';
doo_pagination();

Comment: Ok, but how are you getting the posts? How many posts are you getting and how many are you expecting?
I think it's easier if you create a new question with more details. Make sure to include: what you already did (the page script), what result you got and what were you expecting. I'll try to answer if I know. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much ! I will create new topic for this question :)